# Индекс находился вне границ массива!

Tags: c#, массивы

Почему выводит, что индекс вне границ.
Необходимо вывести сумму всех элементов массива.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("введите кол-во значений в массиве:");
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double[] a = new double[n];
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
        Console.Write("{0: 0}", a[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    double max = a.Max();
    Console.WriteLine("Максимальное:{0}", max);
    double min = a.Min();
    Console.WriteLine("Минимальное:{0}", min);
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
      sum += a[i];
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Сумма м/у мах и мin:{0} ", sum);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

В результате выполнения кода получаю ошибку на строке: sum += a[i];

Comment: Должно быть i < n;

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Трассируйте для n=1 или 2 - и всё будет понятно:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    sum += a[i];
}
```

замените на

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    sum += a[i];
}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!
а я все другое исправлял..

Comment: @roy34 отблагодарите человека не только на словах, но и на деле - поставьте галку напротив этого ответа и вопрос закроете, и человеку баллов добавите.

Answer (score 7):

Причина ошибки состоит в том, что вы пытаетесь использовать индексы там, где это не требуется. В результате когда вы делаете это самостоятельно, вы можете допустить неточность или опечатку.

Так как вы создали массив, содержащий `n` элементов, то допустимый диапазон индексов `[0, n-1]`

```
       for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
                       ^^^^^^^
       {
          sum += a[i];
       }
```

поэтому лучше было бы написать

```
foreach ( var x in a ) sum += x;
```

не ссылаясь на индексы.:)

Answer (score 2):

Как сказали ранее, проблема находится в строке: `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)`.

Для решения этой проблемы я бы подошел немного с другой стороны. Во время перебора коллекции можно использовать не сторонние переменные, которые могут быть ошибочными, а длину массива. Вы в первом `for` использовали это.

К примеру, если `n = 10`, а в массиве у Вас будет девять элементов, то Вы снова получите исключение. Вдруг переменная `n` где-то поменялась?

Можно использовать `Length` (для списков `Count`). Вот так:

```
for (int index = 0; index < arr.Length; index++) {...} // в случае с массивом
for (int index = 0; index < lst.Count; index++)  {...} // в случае со списком
```

Также очень удобен метод [foreach, in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) для перебора коолекции, если Вам не нужны индексы, в таком случае Вам не нужно беспокоиться о знании количества элементов массива:

```
foreach (var item in array) {...}
```

Однако его не следует использовать для добавления или удаления элементов исходной коллекции во избежание непредвиденных побочных эффектов. Если нужно добавить или удалить элементы исходной коллекции, следует использовать цикл [for](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ch45axte.aspx).

С `foreach` немного проще, так как он работает для массивов или коллекций объектов,   реализующих интерфейс `IEnumerable` или `IEnumerable<T>` из `System.Collections.Generic`.

Но и это еще не всё, что может облегчить работу программисту, также имеется метод [Enumerable.Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549046(v=vs.110).aspx), который вычисляет сумму последовательности. И Вам не придется перебирать все элементы коллекции. К примеру:

```
double sum = a.Sum(); // сумма элементов Вашего массива
```

Также можно отметить метод [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx), который применяет к последовательности агрегатную функцию. К примеру, получение суммы будет таким:

```
double sum = a.Aggregate((result, item) => result + item);
```

Comment: _foreach_ неудобен, если нужны индексы

Comment: @Grundy, бесспорно. Но это как альтернатива, когда они не нужны и нужно перебрать коллекцию. Так-то он очень удобен.

Comment: до кучи, можно еще про [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx) пару слов сказать